# Updating entity definition for exisitng entities in datastore

Tags: entity-framework, google-app-engine

I have an app engine(Java) connected android application. I have an entity with some fields. Now I want to add another field to the entity in the new version of the app engine project. But I already have existing entities in the datastore. How can I update existing entities so that it includes the new field?

Answer (score 1):

Add the new field to the model. and you will have it in the datastore, if you want to assign them values , loop through the entities and assign values and put them , other wise the datastore will return None for the records where the new field is not set

Comment: but datastore viewer in my account dont show the column for the new fields.

Comment: And how to loop through the existing entities after I upload the new version of the app engine project?

Comment: I think as long as there is no value in that particular column it won't show it. And to loop through entities and update, well it's simple code "get all, loop through, update parameter, put back in datastore".

Comment: >> **but datastore viewer in my account dont show the column for the new fields.**    That's because Datastore viewer knows nothing about your models and code, it only shows what's in the datastore. Updating the model in the code is not going to magically update all your data. DB/NDB is NoSQL which is different from SQL DBs. As previously suggested all you need is to loop through your old data and update every entity, but only if you really need it. In many cases bulk update would be very expensive for large amounts of data so you would update the entities on need basis.